# How does $(0,y) = (y,0)\cdot(0,1)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was reading a script and cannot understand how does $(0,y) = (y,0)\cdot(0,1)$ in the second line. How can we say this? The section is  "rebuilding the complex numbers from ground up" and this is a multiplication of 2 tuples.

[image: The image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of the representation $(a,b) = a+bi$, we obtain

$(y,0)\cdot (0,1) = y\cdot i= yi =(0,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we write complex numbers as an ordered pair of real numbers $(a,b)$ then the rules of arithmetic are

- $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$
- $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ab-bd,ad+bc)$

This example justifies the second, and presumably there were earlier sections saying we want something like

- A distributive property
- Real scaling such as $(a,0)\cdot (c,d)=(ac,ad)$
- A square root of $-1$ so $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(1,0)$

and the second gives $(y,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,y)$

but we would need to see the context to be sure